# Identify sludge/fungus that appeared overnight

Tags: identification, fungus

I got up this morning to water and this white foamy fungus looking thing was in my garden. It wasn’t here yesterday so this is quite a bit of growth overnight.

I don’t believe I’m overwatering. It’s incredibly hot right now so I water early in the morning and everything dries out by evening.

[image: fungus blob]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a slime mould, often commonly known charmingly as Dog Vomit slime mould - its actual name is *Fuligo septica*. It appears usually during very damp weather, or in damp areas, in spring/early summer and again in fall, and is likely to be seen on anything woody, including wood chips, though it can sometimes appear in lawns. It will just disappear as the area dries out and is not a threat to any planting you have, it's just not pleasant to look at. Further info here http://midwestnaturalist.com/fuligo_septica.html